# Автоматически добавить примечания (подписи) к столбчатой диаграмме

Tags: python, списки, matplotlib, аннотации

Здравствуйте, форумчане. 
В данный момент работаю со списками в Python. Получилось построить диаграмму, ссылаясь на данные из двух списков. Остался последний этап, когда надо отметить пики используя функцию annotation(). В моем случае имеется два списка, в первом из которых хранится информация с названиями 8 городов: listx = ['Paris', 'Moscow', 'Rome''London', .....]. Задача следующая: На получившейся диаграмме нужно отметить пики, которые будут соответсвовать городам из списка. Например, для первой точки-Paris, для второй-Moscow и т.д. Функция должна выполнять эту операцию автоматически, просто ссылаясь на список.
Заранее благодарю.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы можете привести небольшой пример данных в вопросе?

Comment: listx = ['Paris', 'Moscow', 'Rome', 'London',...]
listy = [150, 360, 430, 455,...]
barlistx = [i * 8 for i, _ in enumerate(listx)]
barlisty = [j for _, j in enumerate(listy)]
pyplot.scatter(barlistx, barlisty)
pyplot.title(u'Title')
pyplot.xlabel(r'X axis')
pyplot.ylabel(r'Y axis')
pyplot.show()
pyplot.savefig('Final.png', format='png')

Comment: Вот в данный код надо добавить функцию, которая будет автоматически брать данные из списка listx и отмечать вершины полученной диаграммы.

Comment: Нажмите кнопку "править" под вопросом, чтобы добавить код в вопрос. В комментарии он не очень читаемый

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пример:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def autolabel(rects, labels=None, height_factor=1.01):
    for i, rect in enumerate(rects):
        height = rect.get_height()
        if labels is not None:
            try:
                label = labels[i]
            except (TypeError, KeyError):
                label = ' '
        else:
            label = '%d' % int(height)
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., height_factor*height,
                '{}'.format(label),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

cities = ['Paris','Moscow','Rome','London']
values = [175,380,445,470]

bars = plt.bar(cities, values)
ax = plt.gca()
autolabel(ax.patches, cities, height_factor=1.01)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если не указывать `labels` при вызове функции, то напечатаются величины:

```
autolabel(ax.patches, height_factor=0.85)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE:**

> как сделать так, чтобы текст находился на уровне пиков, а по оси x
>   распологались числа?

```
bars = plt.bar(cities, values)
ax = plt.gca()
autolabel(ax.patches, cities, height_factor=1)
plt.xticks(cities, values)
ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтобы сохранить оригинальную последовательность данных (`plt.bar()` сортирует значения `X` по умолчанию):

```
x = list(map(str, range(len(cities))))
bars = plt.bar(x, values)
ax = plt.gca()
autolabel(ax.patches, cities, height_factor=1)
plt.xticks(x, values)
ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все работает. А случайно не знаете, как сделать так, чтобы текст находился на уровне пиков, а по оси x распологались числа?

Comment: @u_lialia, чтобы текст находился на уровне пиков - используйте `height_factor=1`. Какие числа вы хотите по оси `X` отображать?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

Comment: Спасибо большое, благодаря вашим ответам моя задача решена!