# Подписать seaborn.catplot столбики цифрами из датасета, подскажите как

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Доброго дня уважаемые члены комьюнити.
Есть датасет с выручкой из мед центра.
Строю sns.catplot по месяцам с параметром kind = 'bar', но встал вопрос в подписи столбиков реальными цифрами, например чтобы средний чек терапии был подписан числом для наглядности, число конечно из реальных данных.
Кто то сталкивался с этим? подскажите как реализовать. Пример кода ниже.
Не исключаю, что придется использовать другой способ для построения графика, я открыт к предложениям и премного благодарен заранее.

```
gr = data.groupby(['месяц', 'Направление']).agg({'Пациент':'nunique', 'Сумма со скидкой':'sum'})
gr['Средний чек по направлению'] = gr['Сумма со скидкой'] / gr['Пациент']
gr = gr.reset_index()
for col in ['Сумма со скидкой', 'Пациент', 'Средний чек по направлению']:
    a = sns.catplot(y = col, x = 'Направление',col = 'месяц',kind = 'bar', data = gr)
    a.set_xticklabels(rotation = 90)
    plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно как должен выглядеть результат... Вам [что-то вроде этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/801424/211923) нужно?

Comment: Да похоже на то что надо, подписать столбики цифрами именно на sns.catplot.

Comment: ну тогда предоставьте воспроизводимый пример данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) ;)